# invalid signatures EXPKEYSIG

Tags: apt

sorry if I did something dumb but I'd really appreciate some help.

this comes up whenever I try to check for updates

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_18.04  Release: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 2F7F0DA5FD5B64B9 home:strycore OBS Project <home:strycore@build.opensuse.org>
W: Failed to fetch http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_18.04/Release.gpg  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 2F7F0DA5FD5B64B9 home:strycore OBS Project <home:strycore@build.opensuse.org>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Moderator Note: The `wget` link here is no longer operational as that repository no longer publishes Ubuntu 18.04 repository lists or key data.  However, the content of this post was left alone for historical reasons, and should not be flagged as 'broken link' in reviews.

You have to visit the [repository page](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home%3Astrycore&package=lutris) and re-add the repository signing key again:

```
wget -nv https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:strycore/xUbuntu_18.04/Release.key -O Release.key
sudo apt-key add - < Release.key
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: "2021-01-04 15:05:03 ERROR 404: Not Found."

Comment: For Ubuntu 20.04 :
`wget -nv http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/pzz/xUbuntu_20.04/Release.key -O Release.key`

Comment: The repo at http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/pzz/ stops at 20.04: Do you know where to find this `Release.key` for later versions, e.g. 21.04?

Comment: For Ubuntu 18.04: `wget -nv http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/pzz/xUbuntu_18.04/Release.key -O Release.key`

Comment: The point is go to the repository page. The page in this answer is no longer available. Hence 404. If you experience this same error then go to the ```<URL_written_here>``` in the following message ```An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: <URL_written_here> ./ InRelease:```