# getting Signature Key Error while running sudo apt-get update

Tags: 20.04, gnome-terminal

[open screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DU8DF.png)

Hello, I am getting the error of Signature or Key, please refer to the attached screenshot (above link), please check & help me with how to solve it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Chrome PPA upgrade invalid signature](https://askubuntu.com/questions/599112/google-chrome-ppa-upgrade-invalid-signature)

Comment: but in above screenshot, not only issue is with Google's Signature/Key, Skype for Linux is also there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [invalid signatures EXPKEYSIG](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1129025/invalid-signatures-expkeysig)